# Height of a dynamic cell - SWIFT

Tags: swift, uitableview, dynamic, height, cell

How can I get the height of a dynamic cell from the custom cell view.

I tried
`let height = contentView.layer.frame.height` and
`let height = contentView.frame.height`
but all cells return 44 though the cells are different height.

On the viewController I have `tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension`.

Can anyone please help. Thanks

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights?

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 version. This should work.

```
func cellHeight(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    return cell?.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height ?? 0
}
```

You can call this function after `tableView.reloadData()`. For example:

```
tableView.reloadData()
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) 
let height = cellHeight(for: indexPath)
print(height)
```

> `Important`: You need to configure your cell correctly to be dynamic-heighted.

You don't have to call `tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension` because it's default value.
More importantly, you need to set `tableView.estimatedRowHeight` properly.